# Extracting Numbers From a Table on a Website

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract data from a website for personal use. I only want the precipitation at the top of the hour. I am nearly complete but I cannot sum the data up. I think its because its returning null values, and/or because the data are not all integers? Maybe using a for loop is incorrect?

Here is the code:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

url = 'http://www.saiawos2.com/K61/15MinuteReport.php'
page = urllib2.urlopen(url) 
soup  = BeautifulSoup(page.read())

table = soup.findAll('table')[0]
rows = table.findAll('tr')

second_columns = []
thirteen_columns = []

for row in rows[1:]:
    second_columns.append(row.findAll('td')[1]) #Column with times
    thirteen_columns.append(row.findAll('td')[12]) #Precipitation Column

for second, thirteen in zip(second_columns, thirteen_columns):
    times = ['12:00','11:00','10:00','09:00','08:00','07:00','06:00',
         '05:00','04:00','03:00','02:00','01:00','00:00','23:00',
         '22:00','21:00','20:00','19:00','18:00','17:00','16:00',
         '15:00','14:00','13:00',]
    time = '|'.join(times) 
    if re.search(time, second.text):
        pcpn = re.sub('[^0-9]', '', thirteen.text) #Get rid of text
        print sum(pcpn[1:]) #Print sum and get rid of leading zero
```

Perhaps there is an easy way to do this, but this is what I have so far. When I sum(pcpn) it gives the following error for the line with the print statement:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'unicode'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `sum` tries to find the sum of list of integers where as you have passed a list of unicode characters which it cannot sum.

All you need to do is to map each element of the list to `int` and pass it to sum.

```
if re.search(time, second.text):
        pcpn = re.findall(r'[0-9.]+', thirteen.text) 
        print sum( float(x) for x in pcpn )
```

**What it does?**

- `re.findall(r'[0-9.]+', thirteen.text)` rather than using  the `re.sub` function we use [`re.findall()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) which will give you a list of matches, which can then be passed to the `sum()` function. Here the match is digits.
- `sum( float(x) for x in pcpn )` Maps each element to `float` and find the sum.

  - `( float(x) for x in pcpn )` is a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) statement which creates elements on the go.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response and detailed information!

I am getting syntax error for the "int" in the so called generator statement. Im not sure why. Like I said, I am fairly new to programming. Thanks again.

Comment: @Joe_OU_Wx Sorry for that it was a typo. it should be `in` and not `int`. As in `print sum( int(x) for x in pcpn )`. Corrected in answer

Comment: Thanks again for the quick reply! Your fix worked; however, it is not returning the entire sum which should be 1.93 total inches of rainfall. Your suggestion has greatly improved where I stand though. Much appreciated. I just need to figure out how to get the sum correct and preferably in the right decimal format  to the hundredths place (X.XX or XX.XX). Maybe I need to store the output values somewhere, add a decimal and then sum it?

Comment: @Joe_OU_Wx 2 fixes wil do the work 1) change the regex to `[0-9.]+` so that it finds decimal number instead of integers. 2) rather than using `int()` to convert we can use `float()` so that it returns the decimal number from the string. I have edited my answer with the corrections.

Comment: I should also note the website gives the precipitation like P0103. The P is for precipitation coding. It is inferred that a decimal lies before the last two digits. As a result, when my code returns 103, this is actually 1.03 inches of rainfall.

Comment: Hmm. I did the changes. Still not returning the total sum of 1.93. It outputs the precipitation for every hour but not the total.

Comment: Is it because the print is embedded within the for loop?